# Why is my WWW-Subdomain not indexed?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I am currently working on a project: [BLZ-Aktuell](http://www.blz-aktuell.de)

When I am searching for `site:www.blz-aktuell.de` there are no results. If I do a search for `site:blz-aktuell.de` the search works correct.

Do anyone know what this is about?

Hint: I am using CakePHP, that needed to be added a htaccess file in the root directory. This is the source:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that Google indexed the pages on blz-aktuell.de first, then came across the www.blz version. Since the content of the pages are identical, the second one is discarded to prevent double information in the database. Search around for 'duplicate content' on Google for what that is all about.

Instead of returning the same page under a different URL (www.blz-aktuell.de and blz-aktuell.de) it is recommended that you pick which of those URLs is the 'main' name for your website. If a request is done to one of the alternatives, a 302 redirect should be given to point the visitor to the main site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also aked in the google forums and was redirected to the webmaster documentation. I think I will also have to read through this.

The Problem is, that my client want that there are search results for both domains.

Fortunately, within the last days, there are also some results when searching for the "www..."-domain.